# Turn a UITableViewCell into a row of Buttons/GestureRecognizers on tap?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface

First time asking a question here, bear with me.

So I want to achieve something that looks vaguely like this.

[image]

I want upon tapping a single cell to turn it into a row of smaller buttons, the combined width of the buttons taking up the entire cell. How can I do that in a nicely animated way? Is there anything prebuilt, etc. I could use?

Comment: What did you try / search for / ideas you had?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us your code? Have you already tried something?

Comment: @Wain: I've been looking at potential animations in Quartz, but I'm kind of confused as to where to start. I know I can simply add lines and labels programatically, but I'm not sure how to do it in an animated way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` helps you instead of `tap gesture` ?

// add a new property to your class named `isTapped`. When you select a row update this value to true. Then reload tableview.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    updateCell(indexPath.row)
  }

  func updateCell(index:Int) {
    yourArray[index].isTapped = true
    tableView.reloadData()
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if yourArray[indexPath.row].isTapped == true {
      return divided cell
    } else {
      return normal cell
    }
  }
```